# Haskell dot dot notation on list - unexpected output

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

One of the questions that came up in one of my lectures was the following:

```
trips :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
trips = [ (x,y,z) | z <- [2..], y <- [2..z-1], x <- [2..y-1] ]

What is the first five elements output?
```

Now I thought I was aware how dot dot notation worked, but when I put the above into a compiler the output is:

(2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 6) etc.

How does this happen?

I thought if things begun with [2..] then all the subsequent lists would begin with two? z is defined as [2..] yet it never once displays 2 as the third int. I'm obviously missing something here but I'm not entirely sure what.

Comment: Imagine it as a for-loop which increases its nesting from left to right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[ (x,y,z) | z <- [2..], y <- [2..z-1], x <- [2..y-1] ] =
[ (x,y,2) | y <- [2..2-1], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
[ (x,y,3) | y <- [2..3-1], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
[ (x,y,4) | y <- [2..4-1], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
... =
[ (x,y,2) | y <- [2..1], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
[ (x,y,3) | y <- [2..2], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
[ (x,y,4) | y <- [2..3], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
... =
[ (x,y,2) | y <- [], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
[ (x,y,3) | y <- [2], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
[ (x,y,4) | y <- [2,3], x <- [2..y-1] ] ++
...
```

Note the range `y <- [2..2-1]` i.e. `y <- [2..1]` i.e. `y <- []`. Because of this, there are no triples `(x,y,2)` to generate.

Similarly, when `y` is `2`, the range `z <- [2..y-1]` will generate nothing, and we do not get triples of the form `(x,2,3)`.